# tt_news Previous Article always shown on translated single view pages

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, tt-news

I am currently troubleshooting a TYPO3 6.2 LTS Site with latest tt_news v3.6.0.

There are two problems that might related to each other.

Issue #1: When I configure tt_news is with plugin.tt_news.showTitleAsPrevNextLink = 1
The Prev and Next Link in the SingleView is always displayed in the default language. The News it self is shown correctly.

Issue #2: As I couldn't find a solution for issue #1 I've change the config to plugin.tt_news.showTitleAsPrevNextLink = 0.
With this setting tt_news is always showing the previous link, even if there is no previous news. But this behaviour is only in language_uid 1 (italy) & 2 (french), the default (german) language and 3 (english) are working fine.

Any help is really appreciated. Thank's alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry no help here, but an explanation.

This problem is mentioned in the sourcecode tt_news\pi\class.tx_ttnews.php line 2027, which tells that the language overlay is to be implemented (since 5.5.2009) for next and prev links.

Original message:

```
/**
 * TODO: 05.05.2009
 * lang overlay
 */
```

The only fix is to switch to static text as "next article", "previous article" using TS
plugin.tt_news.showTitleAsPrevNextLink = 0

Comment: Thanks mate, that what I did at the end. :-)